# Does LINQ perform slower when extracting results to a List?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ statement, and I'm finding that it's not running as quickly as I'd like. Are there other variations that run faster, or is there another way to do it that is faster?

```
var products = session.Products.Where(x => x.Supplier.Address.State == "HI").ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you think it spells trouble for performance? (I'm not saying it doesn't, but your post doesn't give any indication of actual benchmarks vs. non LINQ operations that are equivalent).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Do you have a source for the performance comment?

Comment: Rahwi, this sounds like you read it somewhere...can you link to the article?

Comment: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/03/04/using-mongo-with-linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you didn't state is that this was in a blog post for a *specific LINQ provider*. Let's put it in context:

> And now query it:

```
using(var session=new Session()){
   var products = session.Products.Where(x => x.Supplier.Address.State == "HI")
                                  .ToList();
}
```

> … and it works :). This is what’s called a “Deep Graph” query in the ObjectDatabase world and usually spells trouble for performance. To be honest I haven’t pegged this query yet over multiple records – but from what I’ve read this is normal for Mongo and it supports it quite well.

It's not the call to `ToList` which "usually spells trouble for performance" - it's the fact that you're doing a "deep graph query" in an object database. Yes, you're then fetching all the results into memory, but it's the nature of the store which is the cause for concern here.

Comment: Can u explain me a little bit about the "deep graph queries" . or maybe some useful article to read about . I'll be appreciated .

Comment: @Rawhi: I was only quoting the article you linked to. Ask a MongoDB expert :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why this statement "usually spells
>   trouble for performance"

It doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think this fairly common LINQ expression is trouble for performance? Such claims should be backed by some form of performance analysis.

While the LINQ expression methods themselves are fairly simple, I would look at the implementation of the `Supplier.Address.State` chain. Does these properties require a lot of work to be evaluated?

**Update:** given that this is a query against a MongoDB repository and the fact that you're querying for each Product, looking at the value of Supplier's Address's State, makes you go 3 levels "deep" in the object graph. Which, without any smartness in the provider, forces the database to load each "level". Effectively, for each `Product`, in addition to the Product object itself, you're actually loading the Supplier and the Address.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var products =
    (from product in session.Products
    where product.Supplier.State == "HI"
    select product).ToList();
```

but that is only for the readabiity. I don't think the performance is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

How many items present in session.Products? 
How many times this expression is called?

We extensively use Linq in our project, but one time in critical code we were forced to rewrite alike expression with standart foreach operator. Our list contained about 10-20 items but it was called 50000-70000 times. We reduced time cost from about 0.3 second to 0.001 second.

In general usecases (for example, show products on web page) your sample doesn't impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using ToList() will execute your statement right away, and if you would have your query without ToList() execution would be deferred until you reference 'products' variable.  But from performance prospective they would be the same.  If you have some performance issue try to Parallelize your query

```
var products = session.Products.AsParallel().Where(x => x.Supplier.Address.State == "HI").ToList();
```

However now you might have your list in different order as before, so if order is important you might use AsOrdered()

```
var products = session.Products.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Where(x => x.Supplier.Address.State == "HI").ToList();
```